# Relation between OD with different microbial growth

Tags: microbiology

Equal volumes of cell suspensions of Escherichia coli, Saccharomyces cerevisiae, Streptococcus lactis and Mycoplasma pneumoniae, all have the same OD600nm = 0.50. Which cell suspension would have the minimum and maximum number of cells, respectively?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What efforts did you make to answer this homework assignment? If you can't provide them, I'm afraid your question will be downvoted and closed. (see https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework)

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to say with the information you have given. [Here is a paper on the subject if you are interested](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep38828). The relationship between OD and cell count depends on morphology and size, which in turn depend on culture condition, strain, etc...

Comment: Based on size, and if this is a homework question, you might expect yeast to be the largest and *Mycoplasma* to be the smallest.